# What determines if a photon is displayed as light or not?

Tags: visible-light, photons, wave-particle-duality, virtual-particles, carrier-particles

A photon is the particle of light. But a photon is also a force carrier and plays a role in many other situations. What I don’t understand is what determines if it shows up as light or not? Is it just a high concentration or pattern? Why don’t photons show up in all situations?

Answer (score 3):

Photons are present in all electromagnetic interactions. Sometimes they are virtual (e.g., in the case of electrostatic interactions), and sometimes real (e.g., in the case of electromagnetic radiation). For a photon to be perceived as light, it must a) be real; b) have the right range of wavelength (or frequency, or energy); and c) must be detected by your eye (or another light detector).

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is correct. Let me add a few things.

Photons are the quanta of light, and the quanta of energy, that is, the smallest amount of involved in an interaction.

> In physics, a quantum (plural quanta) is the minimum amount of any physical entity (physical property) involved in an interaction. The fundamental notion that a physical property can be "quantized" is referred to as "the hypothesis of quantization".[1] This means that the magnitude of the physical property can take on only discrete values consisting of integer multiples of one quantum.
>   For example, a photon is a single quantum of light (or of any other form of electromagnetic radiation).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum

Light is a type of EM waves ( we use light for visible and invisible), but EM waves include all other wavelength, including for example radiosignals.

> In physics, electromagnetic radiation (EM radiation or EMR) refers to the waves (or their quanta, photons) of the electromagnetic field, propagating (radiating) through space, carrying electromagnetic radiant energy.[1]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation

That is I assume you are asking about visible light, and in that case it does not matter what the number of photons actually is reaching our eyes (or a detector), since the human eye can detect single photons (though to actually perceive it you need more).

> The human eye is very sensitive but can we see a single photon?  The answer is that the sensors in the retina can respond to a single photon.  But neural filters only allow a signal to pass to the brain to trigger a conscious response when at least about five to nine arrive within less than 100 ms.  If we could consciously see single photons we would experience too much visual "noise" in very low light, so this filter is a necessary adaptation, not a weakness.

http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Quantum/see_a_photon.html

You are asking what determines whether photons are called light or not.

So photons make up all (are the quanta of) EM waves, certain wavelengths are called light (in your case visible), and in the case of visible wavelength our eyes (or a detector) can detect even single photons.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I guess someone disliked the mostly-quotes answer.

Answer (score -1):

At our present understanding of physics, photons are elementary particles, in the axiomatic table of the [standard model of particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model). This model is mathematically based on quantum field theories.

The understanding is that the underlying layer of nature is quantum mechanical, and all classical theories are limits, emerge from this underlying level. A bit how thermodynamics can be shown to emerge from statistical mechanics.

It can be shown that the classical electromagnetic wave,light, emerges from a quantum mechanical superposition of zillions of photons. And not only the frequencies of visible light, but all electromagnetic waves are a superposition of photons that have energy$=h*ν$, where $h$ is thePlanck constant and  $ν$ the frequency of the emergent classical wave.

> What I don’t understand is what determines if it shows up as light or not?

As discussed above, a photon is a building component of electromagnetic waves, of which visible light is a small part of frequencies. It is never by itself "light". Light needs the superposition of very many photons in order to emerge as a perception.

> Is it just a high concentration or pattern?

It is high concentration and the mathematics of wavefunction superposition that make what is called "light"

> Why don’t photons show up in all situations?

They do, but they are so dense that special experiments are needed to display their existence.

[This single photon double slit experiment](https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/)t may help in understanding how single photons add up to a phenomenon that becomes a light pattern.

Comment: There are cameras that can detect single photons. And the human eye does not need zillions either. One can see the faintest visible stars when about a hundred photons or a few dozen enter the pupil within 50 ms.

Comment: @Pieter  So? I gave a link for single photon detection. The question I amanswerng  is about "A photon is displayed as light", it is a large number of photons that make light, photons are not light, in the same way bricks and cement are not a building. The building emerges from bricks and cement, I am trying to say.

Comment: You keep claiming that it needs a large number of photons to make light. And you claim that the double-slit experiment explains how. I don't agree with those statements.

Comment: @Pieter . Beliefs are free, physics models need formulas and mathematics. The photon mathematics has electric and magnetic fields only in the wavefunction, i.e. it does not wave in the real (x,y,z,t) space as the experiment shows and the mathematics fits. It is only the probability that waves in space. Think about it, how can it be the classical light cut up, if it cannot be described mthematically  as a wave in space?

Comment: How can I see a star with a photon flux of far fewer than your "zillions" of photons passing through the pupil of my eye? How can the Hubble telescope see stars when just a few photons are reflected by the the large mirror? Observation trumps formulas and math.

Comment: @Pieter The eye and the telescopes see light, not single photons. see the single photon at at time double slit experiment . it needs over 500.000 photons in the rightmost frame to see the classical wave interference./existence

Comment: Maybe i'm confused, b/c I normally agree with anna v, but it seems like you're(anna) equating see/perceiving light in general to seeing/visualizing a single photon interference pattern.  I think the OP is asking about the former not the latter.

Comment: @BradS thanks for the comment. I have edited